# Python Twitter API result does not match documentation: 'urls' field

Tags: python, twitter, pymongo

I'm seeing a different format for a tweet status than I was expecting given the documentation.

```
import twitter
python_client = get_client() #however you want to do this
tweet_id = 577280319092613121
print client.GetStatus(tweet_id).AsDict()['urls']

{u'https://t.co/8JgjULu4jB': u'https://instagram.com/p/0RSj3ooyL-/'}
```

But the documentation (specifically [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#urls)) that each entry in the urls field should be a dictionary like so:

```
{
  "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/XdXRudPXH5",
  "expanded_url": "https:\/\/blog.twitter.com\/2013\/rich-photo-experience-now-in-embedded-tweets-3",
  "display_url": "blog.twitter.com\/2013\/rich-phot\u2026",
  "indices": [80, 103]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

---

Edit (after [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29069533/3393459)):

I am trying to store some tweets in MongoDB using pymongo. Originally I tried to just insert `status.AsDict()` into my collection, but  MongoDB does not allow the `.` character in keys. So I have two questions:

1. For my education, why does the python-twitter module use this storage structure instead of following the documentation (which seems more 'natural' to me)?
2. More practically, are there other places where the status.AsDict() is going to have similar behavior (realigning the keys/values from the API documentation)?

Comment: Try [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

When you select `urls` from `AsDict()` data, it returns them in the form

```
{url: expanded_url}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I noticed! I realize my question is not particularly clear about what I want. I'll edit.